# Problem with RecyclerView Adapter in Android App

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, recyclerlistview

I'm having a problem with RecyclerView and my adapter. The messages inside the RecyclerView are showing too small in the layout, here you can see in an image: [Click to see the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFwrg.png)

MessageAdapter.java:

```
public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.MessageAdapterViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Message> messages;
    public static final int MSG_TYPE_LEFT = 0;
    public static final int MSG_TYPE_RIGHT = 1;

    public MessageAdapter(Context context, List<Message> messages) {
        this.context = context;
        this.messages = messages;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        assert firebaseUser != null;
        if (messages.get(position).getName().equals(firebaseUser.getDisplayName())) {
            return MSG_TYPE_RIGHT;
        } else {
            return MSG_TYPE_LEFT;
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MessageAdapterViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == MSG_TYPE_RIGHT) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat_message_sent, parent, false);
            return new MessageAdapterViewHolder(view);
        } else {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat_message_received, parent, false);
            return new MessageAdapterViewHolder(view);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MessageAdapterViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Message message = messages.get(position);
        ConstraintLayout constraintLayoutMessageSent;
        int viewType = holder.getItemViewType();
        if (viewType == MSG_TYPE_LEFT) {
            holder.textViewChatName.setText(message.getName());
            holder.textViewChatMessage.setText(message.getMessage());
            holder.textViewChatMessageDate.setText(message.getHourminute());
            holder.imageViewChatUserProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, UserProfileActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("username", message.getName());
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        } else {
            constraintLayoutMessageSent = holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.constraintLayoutMessageSent);
            holder.textViewChatMessage.setText(message.getMessage());
            holder.textViewChatMessageDate.setText(message.getHourminute());
            holder.imageViewChatMessageStatus.setImageDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_message_sent, null));
            constraintLayoutMessageSent.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(holder.itemView.getContext());
                    builder.setMessage(R.string.delete_message)
                            .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                    deleteMessage(position);
                                }
                            }).setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                            dialogInterface.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    builder.create();
                    builder.show();
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void deleteMessage(int position) {
        String messageKey = messages.get(position).getKey();
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Messages");
        databaseReference.child(messageKey).removeValue();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messages.size();
    }

    public static class MessageAdapterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView textViewChatMessage;
        private TextView textViewChatName;
        private TextView textViewChatMessageDate;
        private ImageView imageViewChatMessageStatus;
        private ImageView imageViewChatUserProfile;

        public MessageAdapterViewHolder(@NonNull final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textViewChatName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewChatName);
            textViewChatMessage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewChatMessage);
            textViewChatMessageDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewChatMessageDate);
            imageViewChatMessageStatus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewChatMessageStatus);
            imageViewChatUserProfile = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewChatUserProfile);
        }
    }
}
```

UserCommentsActivity.java:

```
    public class UserProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Context context;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private String username = "";
    private ImageView imageViewUserProfileProfile;
    private TextView textViewUserProfileName;
    private TextView textViewUserProfileDescription;
    private ConstraintLayout loadingLayout;
    private LottieAnimationView lottieAnimationViewLoading;
    private RecyclerView recyclerViewUserProfileComments;
    private TextView textViewUserProfileNoComments;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_profile);
        username = getIntent().getStringExtra("username");
        context = getApplicationContext();
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbarUserProfile);
        // TODO set the title of the user profile visiting.
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });
        bindUI();
    }

    private void bindUI() {
        loadingLayout = findViewById(R.id.loadingLayout);
        lottieAnimationViewLoading = findViewById(R.id.lottieAnimationViewLoading);
        imageViewUserProfileProfile = findViewById(R.id.imageViewUserProfileProfile);
        textViewUserProfileName = findViewById(R.id.textViewUserProfileName);
        textViewUserProfileDescription = findViewById(R.id.textViewUserProfileDescription);
        recyclerViewUserProfileComments = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewUserProfileComments);
        textViewUserProfileNoComments = findViewById(R.id.textViewUserProfileNoComments);
        getUserInformation();
        getUserComments();
    }

    private void getUserInformation() {
        loadingLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    String description = "";
                    String gender = "";
                    String profile_picture = "";
                    Response response = HttpRequests.getUserInformation(username);
                    String responseBody = Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).string();
                    responseBody = responseBody.replace("\r\n", "");
                    JSONArray responseArray = new JSONArray(responseBody);
                    for (int i = 0; i < responseArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonobject = responseArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        description = jsonobject.getString("description");
                        gender = jsonobject.getString("gender");
                        profile_picture = jsonobject.getString("profile_picture");
                        updateUI(description, gender, profile_picture);
                    }
                } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                    showErrors();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }

    private void getUserComments() {
        loadingLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    List<Message> userMessageList = new ArrayList<>();
                    String name = "";
                    String comment = "";
                    Response response = HttpRequests.getUserComments(username);
                    String responseBody = Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).string();
                    responseBody = responseBody.replace("\r\n", "");
                    JSONArray responseArray = new JSONArray(responseBody);
                    for (int i = 0; i < responseArray.length(); i++) {
                        Message message = new Message();
                        JSONObject jsonobject = responseArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        name = jsonobject.getString("from_user");
                        comment = jsonobject.getString("comment");
                        if (!name.isEmpty() && !comment.isEmpty()) {
                            message.setName(name);
                            message.setMessage(comment);
                            userMessageList.add(message);
                        }
                    }
                    if (userMessageList.size() > 0) {
                        updateComments(userMessageList);
                    }else{
                        updateCommentSection();
                    }
                } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                    showErrors();
                    updateCommentSection();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }

    private void showErrors() {
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.generic_error), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }

    private void updateUI(final String description, final String gender, final String pictureURL) {
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        //Picasso.get()
                        //        .load(pictureURL)
                        //        .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)
                        //        .into(imageViewUserProfileProfile);
                        toolbar.setTitle(username + " - " + getString(R.string.user_profile));
                        textViewUserProfileName.setText(username);
                        if (description.equals("null")) {
                            textViewUserProfileDescription.setText("");
                        } else {
                            textViewUserProfileDescription.setText(description);
                        }
                        loadingLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        lottieAnimationViewLoading.cancelAnimation();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }

    private void updateComments(final List<Message> userMessageList) {
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
                        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
                        recyclerViewUserProfileComments.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
                        MessageAdapter messageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(context, userMessageList);
                        recyclerViewUserProfileComments.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
                        messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        recyclerViewUserProfileComments.scrollToPosition(userMessageList.size() - 1);
                        loadingLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }

    private void updateCommentSection() {
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        recyclerViewUserProfileComments.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        textViewUserProfileNoComments.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        loadingLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

Layouts:

-chat_message_received:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutChatParent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewChatUserProfile"
        android:layout_width="50sp"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:padding="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_person_blue" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayoutMessageItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/message_received_background"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewChatName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/among_us_font"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textViewChatMessage"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="Administrator" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewChatMessage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/among_us_font"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textViewChatMessageDate"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textViewChatName"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewChatName"
            tools:text="This is a test message This is a test This is a test message" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewChatMessageDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/among_us_font"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="12:20" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

-chat_message_sent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayoutMessageSent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/message_sent_background"
        android:fontFamily="@font/among_us_font"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewChatMessage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/among_us_font"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textViewChatMessageDate"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="Test message sent!" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewChatMessageDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/among_us_font"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageViewChatMessageStatus"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageViewChatMessageStatus"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textViewChatMessage"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageViewChatMessageStatus"
            tools:text="12:02" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewChatMessageStatus"
            android:layout_width="18sp"
            android:layout_height="18sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_message_waiting" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

-UserComments Layout:

[Code Link](https://pastebin.com/8vRq9bjf)

Why is doing that to me? I can't even see the messages.

**UPDATE**

The problem was the android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" property in message layouts. I have just removed that and It's working fine.

Comment: There might be 2 things..
1. android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem"
2. fonts
try removing these..

Comment: Yes you're right is the android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" property. Now it's working perfectly.

Comment: glad to hear this.. Please accept this as answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be 2 things..

**1.** android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem"

**2.** fonts

try removing these.. Hope this will solve the issue.